# Background color not appeared on unordered list

Tags: html, css

Below is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .list  {
        list-style-type: none;
        background-color:purple;
      }
      .list li {
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
      }
      .link{
        font-color:white;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="##" class="link">BANK INDIA</a></li>
      <li><a href="##" class="link">APPLY FOR CREDIT CARDS</a></li>
      <li><a href="##" class="link">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="##" class="link">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add background color to the entire list .Somehow its is not appearing .I was unable to figure out the reason.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmecaxoc/1/)**

```
 .list {
     list-style-type: none;

 }
 .list li {
     float: left;
     margin: 5px;
      background-color:purple;
 }
 .link {
     color:red;
 }
```

Instead of adding background color to `.list`, use for `li`. and in .link you need to use `color:white` not `font-color`

Comment: thanks it helped,actually i need both background color and font-color change on top of it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have `float: left`, you need to clear them. Add:

```
.list {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: purple;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Working Snippet**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .list {
        list-style-type: none;
        background-color: purple;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      .list li {
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
      }
      .link{
        color:white;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>

    <ul class="list">
      <li><a href="##" class="link">BANK INDIA</a></li>
      <li><a href="##" class="link">APPLY FOR CREDIT CARDS</a></li>
      <li><a href="##" class="link">ABOUT US</a></li>
      <li><a href="##" class="link">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @HimaRayaprolu Edited the `color`, which you had mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to add overflow hidden where you have added color. Its working for me:

```
 <style>
  .list  {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color:purple;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .list li {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  .link{
    font-color:white;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this one:

please add css

```
.list li {
        float: left;
        margin: 5px;
          background-color:gray;
      }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/1cbo4grd/2/